# Perl: Testing that a file is actually writable as opposed to checking file permissions

Tags: perl, file-permissions

Say I have a file */var/tmp/filename*.

In Perl, I write the following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if (-W /var/tmp/filename)
{
...
}

exit;
```

Will the -W and -w functions (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) check that the file can actually be written to, or only check that the file permissions allow writing?

The reason I ask is that I am writing a script which retrieves a cookie.

This script needs to be able to write the cookie file to the filesystem, but if the filesystem path to the cookie file is read only, the permissions on the file won't matter. So I want to test if the cookiefile is actually writable as opposed to just checking its permissions.

Comment: I don't have any system where I can intentionally make the filesystem read only, so I haven't been able to test it. Hence the question of how does -w and -W work.

Comment: You could try with a cd or dvd. They are read only filesystems.

Comment: No physical access to the server unfortunately as I'm writing this on a cloud server hosted by Rackspace. Also not my server, so I don't have root.

Comment: With linux you can easily make a filesystem and mount it with whatever read/write or read-only option you want. You could do this on a physical linux install, a  VM, or a rented VPS.

Comment: I would be interested in doing this but I thought you needed root to make filesystems.

Comment: The easiest and best way to test if a file is writable is to open it with write or append access and try to write to it.

Comment: What system(s) is this for?

Comment: It could conceivably be run on AIX or Solaris, however it is being designed and tested on a Linux host and likely will only ever run on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your concern is the filesystem, you can check whether it is mounted read-only.  If so, its line in `/proc/mounts` will have `ro`, so open the file and `grep` for lines with `ro` and your filesystem.

This will work only on filesystems that use `/proc` but yours do.

Note that querying with `mount` is less reliable.

A sure-fire way is to attempt to write a file, and I'd use [File::Temp](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) for that.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the -X operators only test the file modes, not whether the file is actually writeable. So you are going to have to test actually performing the operation, and catch any failure.

From http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html :

> The interpretation of the file permission operators -r , -R , -w , -W , -x , and -X is by default based solely on the mode of the file and the uids and gids of the user. There may be other reasons you can't actually read, write, or execute the file: for example network filesystem access controls, ACLs (access control lists), read-only filesystems, and unrecognized executable formats. Note that the use of these six specific operators to verify if some operation is possible is usually a mistake, because it may be open to race conditions.

I have just verified this with a read-only loopback mount of a filesystem-in-a-file on my test system (Ubuntu 16.04) and the -W flag does indeed *incorrectly* report that the file can be written to.

You could use the touch command:

```
$ touch /media/MountPoint/testfile
touch: cannot touch '/media/MountPoint/testfile': Read-only file system
```

This returns a zero-length string on success when run using backtics:

```
unless (length `touch $filename`) 
{
    print "Can write\n";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it also generate a return code? That would seem a better test to my mind.

Comment: If you want the exit value, you can run the same thing with `system`, or look in the `$?` variable ([perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar)).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You could also do something like below:

```
if (-r $file && -w $file) {
    # file exists, I can read and write it
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that is already addressed in the question. I'm wanting to find out if the -w function actually will do an open() call with the '>' operator to test that the file is writable, or if the -w function simply checks the file's permissions with stat().

Comment: It checks permission with stat. `If you are using ACLs, there is a pragma called filetest that may produce more accurate results than the bare stat mode bits.`

Answer (score -1):

In contrast to perl, the bash/sh shell test -w command does check for the filesystem mount, so you can use that, e.g.

```
perl -e 'if (`[ -w . ] || echo NO`) {print "unwritable\n"}'
```